# MVC Additional Custom routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I want to implement a custom route in my MVC app and I just can't get it to work. I want to keep the exist default route as specified when you create your MVC app.

The routes I want to be valid should look like this:

> default: /{controller}/{action}/{id}
>
> new custom: /{controller}/{appid}/{action}/{id}

With the custom domain, I will be passing the appid in with every request, but the {id} should be optional. The routes are thus defined as follow:

```
       routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Updates", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NewPackageRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{appid}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "apps", appid = "00000000000000000000", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

On the AppsController, I have an action method Index:

```
public ActionResult Index(string appid, string id)
```

If I supply the id parameter, this action method is hit as expected. I am expecting this method to also be called if the {id} parameter is not supplied, thus leaving the id parameter as null. This however does not happen.

How should I define my route differently? Should I perhaps rather make use of AttributeRouting for achieve my goal?

I should maybe also add... If I call the Search action on the Apps controller, I can get to the action. This would happen through the default route...

Hope I have all and enough info...

Comment: Specific routes must be before the default routes (the order is important)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes sorry, I should've said that in the post - will edit - I did try to put the default route last...

Comment: Your `NewPackageRoute` route should be `url: "apps/{appid}/Index/{id}",` (and be the first one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my, but I guess I should've tried before I posted this. I left this issue for a day and now I got it working without any effort...

Thanks @StephenMuecke. You did point out the ordering of the routes which I forgot about. I played with the order initially, but at that point I had other issues in the route definitions that caused it not to work.

All I added was as length check on the appid route value and it is working... My routes are defined as follow now:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NewPackageRoute",
    url: "apps/{appid}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Apps", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
    constraints: new { appid = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Updates", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```